# How to have custom sidebar content per article in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I'm in the process of porting an existing website to Joomla. Most pages of this website consist of a **main content area** and a **sidebar** containing additional items relating to the main content, such as (in-page) links, images, additional information, etc.

In Joomla, the main page content would probably be an *article*, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to create the sidebar content in Joomla.

Examples of pages-with-sidebar:
http://www.aikikan.nl/en_watisaikido
http://www.aikikan.nl/dojo?id=2

I'm creating a custom template for this website, so any solutions that require modifying the template are fine as well. What would be the best way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the content of each sidebar in an article and then assign it to a module by means of the [article-as-module extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/content-embed/7528). You can then control the scope for each module (i.e. choose menu postions for which it will be shown) in the admin interface.

Comment: Thanks, the extension is just what I need! I had to figure out that it is possible to have more than 1 instance of an extension, but now it works great. Also, I have grouped the sidebar-content under a separate category, so that it is easy to find / manage.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension called meta mod which is perfect for this sort of thing. It allows you to show modules based on any condition you can evaluate with PHP